# Laptop & Xubuntu - Lid close (for standby screen) = Can’t unlock

Tags: xubuntu

I start with brand new Xubuntu 19.10 (I come from Windows 10).

With my laptop (MSI GS75 Sealth 85F), I have a problem during sleep when I close the cover:

First of all when I close the cover of my laptop, my PC goes to sleep well and the screen locks well (in order to be "protected" by password). I want this, and that's what's configured in my settings.
But when I open the cover of my laptop, the screen often freezes (blocking) ...
I see the wallpaper of my desktop, I see my tabs in my taskbar open, I can move the mouse, but I can not click anywhere ... And the unlock screen (so that I can login) does not even appear ...
To get out of this situation I have to press the power button for a long time to shut down my PC and turn it back on ...

Is there a solution please?

PS: i am French, sorry if i don't speak english well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Give a try : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014800/xubuntu-frozen-when-locking-screen

Comment: Thank. My solution is : add gnoreLid=true in file /etc/UPower/UPower.conf. Is work for me. Thank.